# Finding old NHS Shapefiles?

Tags: data, united-kingdom, health

I'm trying to track down a UK health geography shapefile and have hit a wall. The name of the specific geography that I'm after is 'NHS Area Team'. However I am looking for a historical version as the more recent version of NHS Area Teams have seen lots of mergers due to the shenanigans of NHS reorganisation.

Normally I would go to the ONS geoportal but they have stopped hosting historical data (annoying). I have emailed them about it and they don't seem to have what I'm after.

Here are the areas which I'm trying to obtain (25 in total) from an old ONS article.

I may be able to construct these by dissolving CCG boundaries to match but I'd quite like to have the proper ONS codes for reference too.

[image: ONS NHS Area Team Map]

Comment: https://www.england.nhs.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/lat-senates-pack.pdf might help but its just a picture not a shapefile

Comment: I think this would be better researched at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better answered on OpenData.

Comment: No probs, how do I flag to transfer to openData SE?